# Set variable in a Stored Procedure using a select query in Snowflake

Tags: variables, set, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I am trying to Set variable in a Stored Procedure using a select query in Snowflake. I am using Snow SQL

```
create or replace procedure test()
 returns varchar
 language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER

 as 
 $$
SET qid = (select id from table_name);


return 'Complete';
end;
$$
;
```

Getting the error Error: Session variable '$QID' does not exist

Can you please guide me how to take care of this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of variables:

- [SQL/session variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables)
- [Snowflake Scripting variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables)

Using Snowflake Scripting variable:

```
create or replace procedure test()
returns varchar
language sql
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as 
$$
DECLARE
  qid varchar;
BEGIN
  qid := (select id from table_name limit 1);  -- this query should return single value

  return qid;
end;
$$;
```

---

Related: [Using Session Variables with Caller’s Rights and Owner’s Rights Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript#using-session-variables-with-caller-s-rights-and-owner-s-rights-stored-procedures)

Comment: It worked perfectly! I never thought of using a scripting variable! Thanks so much!